# bash - compare integer value

Tags: bash, shell, testing, compare

I am trying to trap arrow keys without the user hitting the "return" key. The program works except for my attempt to catch the "esc" key. I have tried to compare using everything I can think of with out success. Including string and numeric compares; with and without quotes; single vs double brackets, etc. shellcheck does not report any problems.

Either nothing happens (the esc key is not traped) or I get a syntax error; *"./key-no-return-printf.sh: line 37: [[: ': syntax error: operand expected (error token is "'")"*

i.e. $VALUE -eq 27, $VALUE == 27, $VALUE = 27, "$VALUE" -eq "27", etc.

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
clear

function getkey () {
  read -rs -n1 -t.001 KEYIN         # read 1 chr, no echo, no delay
  VALUE=\'$KEYIN
  if [[ $VALUE -eq 27 ]]; then     # trap esc key
    printf "esc caught\n"
  fi
}

while :; do    # --- Infinite loop ---
  KEYIN=""
  VALUE=0
  getkey
  if [[ $KEYIN == [Qq] ]]; then exit; fi
  if [[ $KEYIN != "" ]]; then printf "%s : %d\n" "$KEYIN" "$VALUE"; fi
done
```

Comment: What exactly is `VALUE=\'$KEYIN` supposed to do? It just sets VALUE to an apostrophe, followed by the content of the string stored in KEYIN.

Comment: Also, which line is line 37? The script you have posted does not seem to have so many lines.

Comment: 1) I had removed my commented file header which through off the error info.  Line #6 above would be the relevant line. 2) The VALUE=\'$KEYIN  was erroneously used because I did not realize it is limited to the printf statement. I blindly used it but 
chrslg's comment below explains why it should not have been used. In a printf it some how returns a decimal - don't ask me how, I have never seen it used before.

Answer (score 2):

Using a different way to get the code of the key works for me:

```bash
VALUE=$(printf %d "'$KEYIN")
if [[ $VALUE -eq 27 ]]; then     # trap esc key
    printf "esc caught\n"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up using your suggestion because it allowed me to continue the use of a sub-routine which is needed for my completed script. I have been able to complete my original script which I did not explain for the purposes of this question and problem. I also appreciated chrslg's additional options which I have added to my permanent notes.

Answer (score 1):

That `'$KEYIN` is a `printf` thing indeed, not a bash thing. So you can't expect `'$KEYIN` to become a decimal representation of an ASCII code by itself (or when storing it in `VALUE`). That is only when passing `'somechar` string to `printf`  that printf will interpret it that way if it matches a `%d` (to mimic what would happen in C if you were `printf("%d", 'somechar')`)

But you don't really need that. You don't really need the decimal representation of `KEYIN` to check if it is an escape. Just do it like you do with other char

```bash
while :; do    # --- Infinite loop ---
  read -rs -n1 -t.001 KEYIN         # read 1 chr, no echo, no delay
  if [[ $KEYIN == [Qq] ]]; then exit; fi
  if [[ $KEYIN == ^[ ]]; then printf "ESC\n"; exit; fi
  if [[ $KEYIN != "" ]]; then printf "%s : %d\n" "$KEYIN" "$VALUE"; fi
done
```

`^[` here being not a `^` followed by a `[`, but an actual escape. With classical vim binding, you can input an escape by typing Ctrl+V first, then the escape key.

If your editor makes it difficult to insert an escape in the code, you can also use octal escaping

```bash
while :; do    # --- Infinite loop ---
  read -rs -n1 -t.001 KEYIN         # read 1 chr, no echo, no delay
  if [[ $KEYIN == [Qq] ]]; then exit; fi
  if [[ $KEYIN == $'\033' ]]; then printf "ESC\n"; exit; fi
  if [[ $KEYIN != "" ]]; then printf "%s : %d\n" "$KEYIN" "$VALUE"; fi
done
```

(`$'xxx'` is C-escape. That means that the string behaves like a string in C-langague. So `\octal` is replaced by character of that octal ascii code. ESCAPE is character 27, so `\033` in octal escaping.  So `$KEYIN == $'\033'` is just the same thing as `$KEYIN == ^[`

Point is: no need to convert the content of `KEYIN` into a decimal code using a subcommand. If you want to compare KEYIN to Escape, just do it directly with ==. All that it takes is to know how to say "ESCAPE" :D